ODE theory - conditions for differentiating an ODE
I’m trying to find out more about solving ODEs, spurred on by my previous question about solving $(x’(t))^2+a(x(t))^2+b=0$ with say $x(0)=1,x(2)=3$. In this case differentiating reveals the equation can be reduced to $x’’(t)+2ax(t)=0$. So my question is can you always apply the derivative to any $x’’(t)=f(t)$? Can it introduce solutions that don’t solve the original equation? Is there a way to generalise this for other differential equations?
I tried to think about it with an example like $u(x)=\sin(u(x))\implies u’(x)=u’(x)\cos(u(x))\implies \cos(u(x))=0$ so in this case it seems to work.
Is there a chapter in a textbook where I can learn more about this?

Differentiating an ODE is not always a valid "move". It may indeed produce superfluous solutions, because its order is increased $-$ like squaring an algebraic equation analoguously $-$, but you can always check their validity by inserting them back into the original differential equation; it is to be noted that sometimes these extraneous solutions don't fulfill the intial/boundary conditions.
Nonetheless, one has to be careful at each step. Contrary to squaring an algebraic equation, the main "danger" here comes from the fact that the derivative is not invertible, because its kernel is non-trivial $-$ it is made of constant functions, obviously. In consequence, usually, some solutions are "lost", because they are "swallowed" into the said kernel.
The ODE you provided, namely $\dot{x}^2 + ax^2 + b = 0$, is a good example. It is differentiated as $2\dot{x}(\ddot{x} + ax) = 0$, which is decomposed into the two subequations $\dot{x} = 0$ and $\ddot{x} + ax = 0$ (assuming $\dot{x} \neq 0$ in that second case), which themselves are solved by $x_1 = const$ and $x_2 = A\sin(\sqrt{a}t) + B\cos(\sqrt{a}t)$. In fact, $x_1$ cannot satisfy your boundary conditions and $x_2 = B\cos(\sqrt{a}t)$, with $B = -\frac{3}{\sqrt{a}\cos(2\sqrt{a})}$, is a valid solution of the original ODE only if $b = -a$. This situation is due to the fact that $\dot{b} = 0$.
This "flaw" of the derivative is particularly damaging when you try to differentiate algebraic equations. For instance, any polynomial equation of degree $n$ may become non-sensical by differentiating it $n$ times (e.g. $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$ becomes $2 = 0$ after two derivatives). Again, this is caused by the fact that those expressions are mapped to zero, because they belong to the kernel of the $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative.
On the other end, since you are interested in techniques for solving ODE, algebraic manipulations are also possible. For instance, your first example can be reparametrized as $\frac{\dot{x}^2}{\alpha^2} + \frac{x^2}{\beta^2} = 1$, which corresponds to an ellipse. It can be translated in polar coordinates as
$$
\begin{cases}
   \dot{x} = \alpha\cos\theta \\
        x  =  \beta\sin\theta
\end{cases},
$$
hence $\dot{x} = \alpha\cos\theta = \beta\dot{\theta}\cos\theta$ and thus $\dot{\theta} = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ when $\cos\theta \neq 0$.

Suppose $a>0$. Differentiating
$$(x’(t))^2+a(x(t))^2+b=0\tag{1}$$
gives
$$ x'(t)(x’’(t)+ax(t))=0. $$
If $x'(t)=0$, then $x(t)\equiv C$ which does not satisfy $x(0)=1,x(2)=3$. So
$$ x’’(t)+ax(t)=0 $$
which has the general solution
$$ x(t)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{a}t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{a}t). $$
Using $x(0)=1,x(2)=3$, one has
$$ x(t)=\frac{3\sin(2\sqrt{a}t)-\sin(2\sqrt{a} (t-2))}{ \sin(2\sqrt{2a})}. $$
So
$$ x'(0)=\frac{\sqrt{a}(3-\cos(2\sqrt{a}))}{\sin(2\sqrt{a})}, x'(2)=\frac{\sqrt{a}(-1+3\cos(2\sqrt{a}))}{\sin(2\sqrt{a})}. $$
Letting $t=0,2$ in (1) gives
$$ a+b+a\frac{(3-\cos(2\sqrt{a}))^2}{\sin^2(2\sqrt{a})}=0. \tag2 $$
and
$$ 9 a+b+a\frac{(-1+3\cos(2\sqrt{a}))^2}{\sin^2(2\sqrt{a})}=0. \tag{3}$$
It is easy to see that (2) and (3) are equivalent. Thus (1) with the boundary conditions $x(0)=1,x(2)=3$ t has a unique solution if and only if (2) or (3) holds. You can treat the case of $a<0$ similarly.
